# What does _git mean in the context of bbappend recipes?

Tags: bitbake

In bitbake, _%.bbappend or _ver.bbappend can be used to indicate which base version of a recipe the append file is intended to modify.  I have also seen _git.bbappend being used but I can't find any documentation on this usage.

I would appreciate any clarification about _git.bbappend in the context of bbappend files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a kind of a habit to give the recipe with the latest status of the package the version `git` e.g. [grubby](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=grubby) .
So, you can see 'git' here as as the version part of the `_ver.bbappend`.